# Doctrine2: Best way to handle many-to-many with extra columns in reference table

Tags: php, orm, model, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm wondering what's the best, the cleanest and the most simply way to work with many-to-many relations in Doctrine2.

Let's assume that we've got an album like [*Master of Puppets* by Metallica](http://www.last.fm/music/Metallica/Master+of+Puppets) with several tracks. But please note the fact that one track might appears in more that one album, like [*Battery* by Metallica](http://www.last.fm/music/Metallica/Master+of+Puppets/Battery) does - three albums are featuring this track.

So what I need is many-to-many relationship between albums and tracks, using third table with some additional columns (like position of the track in specified album). Actually I have to use, as Doctrine's documentation suggests, a double one-to-many relation to achieve that functionality.

```
/** @Entity() */
class Album {
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") */
    protected $id;

    /** @Column() */
    protected $title;

    /** @OneToMany(targetEntity="AlbumTrackReference", mappedBy="album") */
    protected $tracklist;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->tracklist = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function getTracklist() {
        return $this->tracklist->toArray();
    }
}

/** @Entity() */
class Track {
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") */
    protected $id;

    /** @Column() */
    protected $title;

    /** @Column(type="time") */
    protected $duration;

    /** @OneToMany(targetEntity="AlbumTrackReference", mappedBy="track") */
    protected $albumsFeaturingThisTrack; // btw: any idea how to name this relation? :)

    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function getDuration() {
        return $this->duration;
    }
}

/** @Entity() */
class AlbumTrackReference {
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") */
    protected $id;

    /** @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Album", inversedBy="tracklist") */
    protected $album;

    /** @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Track", inversedBy="albumsFeaturingThisTrack") */
    protected $track;

    /** @Column(type="integer") */
    protected $position;

    /** @Column(type="boolean") */
    protected $isPromoted;

    public function getPosition() {
        return $this->position;
    }

    public function isPromoted() {
        return $this->isPromoted;
    }

    public function getAlbum() {
        return $this->album;
    }

    public function getTrack() {
        return $this->track;
    }
}
```

Sample data:

```
             Album
+----+--------------------------+
| id | title                    |
+----+--------------------------+
|  1 | Master of Puppets        |
|  2 | The Metallica Collection |
+----+--------------------------+

               Track
+----+----------------------+----------+
| id | title                | duration |
+----+----------------------+----------+
|  1 | Battery              | 00:05:13 |
|  2 | Nothing Else Matters | 00:06:29 |
|  3 | Damage Inc.          | 00:05:33 |
+----+----------------------+----------+

              AlbumTrackReference
+----+----------+----------+----------+------------+
| id | album_id | track_id | position | isPromoted |
+----+----------+----------+----------+------------+
|  1 |        1 |        2 |        2 |          1 |
|  2 |        1 |        3 |        1 |          0 |
|  3 |        1 |        1 |        3 |          0 |
|  4 |        2 |        2 |        1 |          0 |
+----+----------+----------+----------+------------+
```

Now I can display a list of albums and tracks associated to them:

```
$dql = '
    SELECT   a, tl, t
    FROM     Entity\Album a
    JOIN     a.tracklist tl
    JOIN     tl.track t
    ORDER BY tl.position ASC
';

$albums = $em->createQuery($dql)->getResult();

foreach ($albums as $album) {
    echo $album->getTitle() . PHP_EOL;

    foreach ($album->getTracklist() as $track) {
        echo sprintf("\t#%d - %-20s (%s) %s\n", 
            $track->getPosition(),
            $track->getTrack()->getTitle(),
            $track->getTrack()->getDuration()->format('H:i:s'),
            $track->isPromoted() ? ' - PROMOTED!' : ''
        );
    }   
}
```

The results are what I'm expecting, ie: a list of albums with their tracks in appropriate order and promoted ones being marked as promoted.

```
The Metallica Collection
    #1 - Nothing Else Matters (00:06:29) 
Master of Puppets
    #1 - Damage Inc.          (00:05:33) 
    #2 - Nothing Else Matters (00:06:29)  - PROMOTED!
    #3 - Battery              (00:05:13)
```

### So what's wrong?

This code demonstrates what's wrong:

```
foreach ($album->getTracklist() as $track) {
    echo $track->getTrack()->getTitle();
}
```

`Album::getTracklist()` returns an array of `AlbumTrackReference` objects instead of `Track` objects. I can't create proxy methods cause what if both, `Album` and `Track` would have `getTitle()` method? I could do some extra processing within `Album::getTracklist()` method but what's the most simply way to do that? Am I forced do write something like that?

```
public function getTracklist() {
    $tracklist = array();

    foreach ($this->tracklist as $key => $trackReference) {
        $tracklist[$key] = $trackReference->getTrack();

        $tracklist[$key]->setPosition($trackReference->getPosition());
        $tracklist[$key]->setPromoted($trackReference->isPromoted());
    }

    return $tracklist;
}

// And some extra getters/setters in Track class
```

## EDIT

@beberlei suggested to use proxy methods:

```
class AlbumTrackReference {
    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->getTrack()->getTitle()
    }
}
```

That would be a good idea but I'm using that "reference object" from both sides: `$album->getTracklist()[12]->getTitle()` and `$track->getAlbums()[1]->getTitle()`, so `getTitle()` method should return different data based on the context of invocation.

I would have to do something like:

```
 getTracklist() {
     foreach ($this->tracklist as $trackRef) { $trackRef->setContext($this); }
 }

 // ....

 getAlbums() {
     foreach ($this->tracklist as $trackRef) { $trackRef->setContext($this); }
 }

 // ...

 AlbumTrackRef::getTitle() {
      return $this->{$this->context}->getTitle();
 }
```

And that's not a very clean way.

Comment: How do you handle the AlbumTrackReference? For Example $album->addTrack() or $album->removeTrack()?

Comment: I didn't understand you comment about context. In my opnion the data doesn't depend on context. About `$album->getTracklist()[12]` is  `AlbumTrackRef` object, so `$album->getTracklist()[12]->getTitle()` will return always the title of the track (if you are using the proxy method). While `$track->getAlbums()[1]` is `Album` object, so `$track->getAlbums()[1]->getTitle()` will return always the title of the album.

Comment: Another idea is using on `AlbumTrackReference` two proxy methods, `getTrackTitle()` and `getAlbumTitle`.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

I've opened a similar question in the Doctrine user mailing list and got a really simple answer;

consider the many to many relation as an entity itself, and then you realize you have 3 objects, linked between them with a one-to-many and many-to-one relation.

http://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-user/browse_thread/thread/d1d87c96052e76f7/436b896e83c10868#436b896e83c10868

Once a relation has data, it's no more a relation !

Comment: Does anybody know how can I get the doctrine command line tool to generate this new entity as a yml schema file ? This command: `app/console doctrine:mapping:import AppBundle yml` still generate manyToMany relation for the original two tables and simply ignore the third table instead of concidering it as an entity `:/`

Comment: what is the different between `foreach ($album->getTracklist() as $track) {
    echo $track->getTrack()->getTitle();
}` provided by @Crozin and `consider the relationship as an entity`? I think what he want to ask is how to skip the relational entity and retrieving  the title of a track by using `foreach ($album->getTracklist() as $track) {
    echo $track->getTitle();
}`

Comment: "Once a relation has data, it's no more a relation" This was really enlightening. I just couldn't think about a relation from an entity perspective!

Comment: What about if the relationship was already created and used as a many to many. We realized that we needed extra fields in our many to many so we created a different entity. The trouble is, with existing data, and an existing table with the same name, it doesn't seem to want to be friends. Has anyone tried this before?

Comment: For those wondering: creating an Entity with the (already existing) many-to-many jointable as its table works, however, the entities holding the many-to-many must be adapted to instead one-to-many to the new entity. also interfaces to the outside (getters/setters for the former many-to-many) most likely have to be adapted.

Answer (score 17):

From $album->getTrackList() you will alwas get "AlbumTrackReference" entities back, so what about adding methods from the Track and proxy?

```
class AlbumTrackReference
{
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->getTrack()->getTitle();
    }

    public function getDuration()
    {
        return $this->getTrack()->getDuration();
    }
}
```

This way your loop simplifies considerably, aswell as all other code related to looping the tracks of an album, since all methods are just proxied inside AlbumTrakcReference:

```
foreach ($album->getTracklist() as $track) {
    echo sprintf("\t#%d - %-20s (%s) %s\n", 
        $track->getPosition(),
        $track->getTitle(),
        $track->getDuration()->format('H:i:s'),
        $track->isPromoted() ? ' - PROMOTED!' : ''
    );
}
```

Btw You should rename the AlbumTrackReference (for example "AlbumTrack"). It is clearly not only a reference, but contains additional logic. Since there are probably also Tracks that are not connected to an album but just available through a promo-cd or something this allows for a cleaner separation also.

Comment: Proxy methods doesn't solve the problem in 100% (check my edit). `Btw You should rename the AlbumT(...)` - good point

Comment: Why dont you have two methods? getAlbumTitle() and getTrackTitle() on the AlbumTrackReference object? Both proxy to their respective subobjects.

Comment: The goal is the most *natural* object API. `$album->getTracklist()[1]->getTrackTitle()` is as good/bad as `$album->getTracklist()[1]->getTrack()->getTitle()`. However it seems that I'd have to have two different classes: one for album->track references and another for track->albums references - and that's too hard to implement. So probably that's the best solution so far...

Answer (score 13):

**Nothing beats a nice example**

For people looking for a clean coding example of an one-to-many/many-to-one associations between the 3 participating classes to store extra attributes in the relation check this site out:

[nice example of one-to-many/many-to-one associations between the 3 participating classes](http://web.archive.org/web/20161128070704/http://codemonkeys.be/2013/02/example-of-a-doctrine-2-x-many-to-many-association-class/)

**Think about your primary keys**

Also think about your primary key. You can often use composite keys for relationships like this. Doctrine natively supports this. You can make your referenced entities into ids.
[Check the documentation on composite keys here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html)

Answer (score 10):

I think I would go with @beberlei's suggestion of using proxy methods. What you can do to make this process simpler is to define two interfaces:

```
interface AlbumInterface {
    public function getAlbumTitle();
    public function getTracklist();
}

interface TrackInterface {
    public function getTrackTitle();
    public function getTrackDuration();
}
```

Then, both your `Album` and your `Track` can implement them, while the `AlbumTrackReference` can still implement both, as following:

```
class Album implements AlbumInterface {
    // implementation
}

class Track implements TrackInterface {
    // implementation
}

/** @Entity whatever */
class AlbumTrackReference implements AlbumInterface, TrackInterface
{
    public function getTrackTitle()
    {
        return $this->track->getTrackTitle();
    }

    public function getTrackDuration()
    {
        return $this->track->getTrackDuration();
    }

    public function getAlbumTitle()
    {
        return $this->album->getAlbumTitle();
    }

    public function getTrackList()
    {
        return $this->album->getTrackList();
    }
}
```

This way, by removing your logic that is directly referencing a `Track` or an `Album`, and just replacing it so that it uses a `TrackInterface` or `AlbumInterface`, you get to use your `AlbumTrackReference` in any possible case. What you will need is to differentiate the methods between the interfaces a bit.

This won't differentiate the DQL nor the Repository logic, but your services will just ignore the fact that you're passing an `Album` or an `AlbumTrackReference`, or a `Track` or an `AlbumTrackReference` because you've hidden everything behind an interface :)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

First, I mostly agree with beberlei on his suggestions.  However, you may be designing yourself into a trap.  Your domain appears to be considering the title to be the natural key for a track, which is likely the case for 99% of the scenarios you come across.  However, what if *Battery* on *Master of the Puppets* is a different version (different length, live, acoustic, remix, remastered, etc) than the version on *The Metallica Collection*.

Depending on how you want to handle (or ignore) that case, you could either go beberlei's suggested route, or just go with your proposed extra logic in Album::getTracklist().  Personally, I think the extra logic is justified to keep your API clean, but both have their merit.

If you do wish to accommodate my use case, you could have Tracks contain a self referencing OneToMany to other Tracks, possibly $similarTracks.  In this case, there would be two entities for the track *Battery*, one for *The Metallica Collection* and one for *Master of the Puppets*.  Then each similar Track entity would contain a reference to each other.  Also, that would get rid of the current AlbumTrackReference class and eliminate your current "issue".  I do agree that it is just moving the complexity to a different point, but it is able to handle a usecase it wasn't previously able to.

Answer (score 6):

You ask for the "best way" but there is no best way. There are many ways and you already discovered some of them. How you want to manage and/or encapsulate association management when using association classes is entirely up to you and your concrete domain, noone can show you a "best way" I'm afraid.

Apart from that, the question could be simplified a lot by removing Doctrine and relational databases from the equation. The essence of your question boils down to a question about how to deal with association classes in plain OOP.

Answer (score 6):

I was getting from a conflict with join table defined in an association class ( with additional custom fields ) annotation and a join table defined in a many-to-many annotation.

The mapping definitions in two entities with a direct many-to-many relationship appeared to result in the automatic creation of the join table using the 'joinTable' annotation. However the join table was already defined by an annotation in its underlying entity class and I wanted it to use this association entity class's own field definitions so as to extend the join table with additional custom fields.

The explanation and solution is that identified by FMaz008 above. In my situation, it was thanks to this post in the forum '[Doctrine Annotation Question](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=36745&p=122235)'. This post draws attention to the Doctrine documentation regarding [ManyToMany Uni-directional relationships](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional). Look at the note regarding the approach of using an 'association entity class' thus replacing the many-to-many annotation mapping directly between two main entity classes with a one-to-many annotation in the main entity classes and two 'many-to-one' annotations in the associative entity class. There is an example provided in this forum post [Association models with extra fields](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/doctrine-user/cw8fyH9_ebY):

```
public class Person {

  /** @OneToMany(targetEntity="AssignedItems", mappedBy="person") */
  private $assignedItems;

}

public class Items {

    /** @OneToMany(targetEntity="AssignedItems", mappedBy="item") */
    private $assignedPeople;
}

public class AssignedItems {

    /** @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person")
    * @JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
private $person;

    /** @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Item")
    * @JoinColumn(name="item_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
private $item;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This really useful example. It lacks in the documentation doctrine 2.

Very thank you.

For the proxies functions can be done :

```
class AlbumTrack extends AlbumTrackAbstract {
   ... proxy method.
   function getTitle() {} 
}

class TrackAlbum extends AlbumTrackAbstract {
   ... proxy method.
   function getTitle() {}
}

class AlbumTrackAbstract {
   private $id;
   ....
}
```

and

```
/** @OneToMany(targetEntity="TrackAlbum", mappedBy="album") */
protected $tracklist;

/** @OneToMany(targetEntity="AlbumTrack", mappedBy="track") */
protected $albumsFeaturingThisTrack;
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution is in the documentation of Doctrine. In the FAQ you can see this :

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/faq.html#how-can-i-add-columns-to-a-many-to-many-table

And the tutorial is here :

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html

So you do not anymore do a `manyToMany` but you have to create an extra Entity and put `manyToOne` to your two entities.

**ADD** for @f00bar comment :

it's simple, you have just to to do something like this :

```
Article  1--N  ArticleTag  N--1  Tag
```

So you create an entity ArticleTag

```
ArticleTag:
  type: entity
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  manyToOne:
    article:
      targetEntity: Article
      inversedBy: articleTags
  fields: 
    # your extra fields here
  manyToOne:
    tag:
      targetEntity: Tag
      inversedBy: articleTags
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Updated links: [1 - FAQ](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/faq.html#how-can-i-add-columns-to-a-many-to-many-table), [2 - Tutorials: Composite Primary Keys](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html)

Comment: That's exacly what I was looking for, thank you ! Unfortunatly, there is no yml example for the third use case ! `:(` Could anyone share an exabple of the third use case using yml format ? I would really appriace `:#`

Comment: i've added to the answer your case ;)

Comment: It's incorrect. The entity does not have to be with id (id) AUTO. That's wrong, I'm trying to create the correct example

Comment: i will post a new answer to get if formatted correctly

Answer (score 3):

Unidirectional. Just add the inversedBy:(Foreign Column Name) to make it Bidirectional.

```
# config/yaml/ProductStore.dcm.yml
ProductStore:
  type: entity
  id:
    product:
      associationKey: true
    store:
      associationKey: true
  fields:
    status:
      type: integer(1)
    createdAt:
      type: datetime
    updatedAt:
      type: datetime
  manyToOne:
    product:
      targetEntity: Product
      joinColumn:
        name: product_id
        referencedColumnName: id
    store:
      targetEntity: Store
      joinColumn:
        name: store_id
        referencedColumnName: id
```

I hope it helps.
See you.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to achieve what you want with [Class Table Inheritance](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/docs/reference/inheritance-mapping/en) where you change AlbumTrackReference to AlbumTrack:

```
class AlbumTrack extends Track { /* ... */ }
```

And `getTrackList()` would contain `AlbumTrack` objects which you could then use like you want:

```
foreach($album->getTrackList() as $albumTrack)
{
    echo sprintf("\t#%d - %-20s (%s) %s\n", 
        $albumTrack->getPosition(),
        $albumTrack->getTitle(),
        $albumTrack->getDuration()->format('H:i:s'),
        $albumTrack->isPromoted() ? ' - PROMOTED!' : ''
    );
}
```

You will need to examine this throughly to ensure you don't suffer performance-wise.

Your current set-up is simple, efficient, and easy to understand even if some of the semantics don't quite sit right with you.

Answer (score 0):

While getting all album tracks form inside album class, you'll generate one more query for one more record. That's because of proxy method. There's another example of my code (see last post in topic): http://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-user/browse_thread/thread/d1d87c96052e76f7/436b896e83c10868#436b896e83c10868

Is there any other method to resolve that? Isn't a single join a better solution?

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution as described in the [Doctrine2 Documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional)

```
<?php
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/** @Entity */
class Order
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue */
    private $id;

    /** @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customer") */
    private $customer;
    /** @OneToMany(targetEntity="OrderItem", mappedBy="order") */
    private $items;

    /** @Column(type="boolean") */
    private $payed = false;
    /** @Column(type="boolean") */
    private $shipped = false;
    /** @Column(type="datetime") */
    private $created;

    public function __construct(Customer $customer)
    {
        $this->customer = $customer;
        $this->items = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->created = new \DateTime("now");
    }
}

/** @Entity */
class Product
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue */
    private $id;

    /** @Column(type="string") */
    private $name;

    /** @Column(type="decimal") */
    private $currentPrice;

    public function getCurrentPrice()
    {
        return $this->currentPrice;
    }
}

/** @Entity */
class OrderItem
{
    /** @Id @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Order") */
    private $order;

    /** @Id @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product") */
    private $product;

    /** @Column(type="integer") */
    private $amount = 1;

    /** @Column(type="decimal") */
    private $offeredPrice;

    public function __construct(Order $order, Product $product, $amount = 1)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
        $this->product = $product;
        $this->offeredPrice = $product->getCurrentPrice();
    }
}
```