# Link tables with extra column in Symfony 2 / Doctrine

Tags: doctrine, symfony

In a database I have the tables `User`, `Group` and `UsersInGroup` and generate the entities from the database using the Symfony 2 console. The table `UsersInGroup` is not generated as an entity but is partly generated into `User` and `Group`. This would be perfect if `UsersInGroup` hat only two columns `userId` and `groupId` (together primarykey), in this case the table `UsersInGroup` also contains a third column `Role`. This field is can never be filled using the generated entities

How should I fill the `Role` column in the tabel `UsersInGroup`?

Comment: Did you try defining `UsersInGroup`? Try to match the automatic definition and add your own column and relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare your relation table manually and to map the relations.

You'll find an interesting discussion here:

[Doctrine2: Best way to handle many-to-many with extra columns in reference table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542243/doctrine2-best-way-to-handle-many-to-many-with-extra-columns-in-reference-table)