# Doctrine 2 Many to Many relation with additional columns in join table

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

So, I have been playing round with using doctrine for a while now and have it in some basic projects, but i decided to go back and have an in depth look into what it can do.

Ive now decided to switch to symfony 2 as my framework of choice and am looking into what doctrine 2 can do in more depth.

One thing i have been trying to get my head around is the many to many relationship within doctrine. I am starting to build a recipe system and am working on the relation between recipe and ingredients which gave me 3 entities, recipe, recipeIngredient and ingredient. The reason i cannot use a direct many to many relation is because i want to store two additional columns in the join table ( unit and quantity ) for each ingredient.

The problem i am having at the moment is that the entities persist ok, but the recipe_id in the join table is not inserted. I have tried everything i can think off and been through every thread and website looking for an answer . I am sure it is something completely obvious that i am missing. Please help, below is the code i have so far:

```
<?php
namespace Recipe\RecipeBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="recipe")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Recipe{

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RecipeIngredient", mappedBy="recipe", cascade=       {"persist"})
 */
protected $ingredients;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @var string $title
 *
 */
protected $title;
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->ingredients = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Add ingredients
 *
 * @param \Recipe\RecipeBundle\Entity\RecipeIngredient $ingredients
 * @return Recipe
 */
public function addIngredient(\Recipe\RecipeBundle\Entity\RecipeIngredient $ingredients)
{
    $ingredients->setRecipe($this);
    $this->ingredients[] = $ingredients;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove ingredients
 *
 * @param \Recipe\RecipeBundle\Entity\RecipeIngredient $ingredients
 */
public function removeIngredient(\Recipe\RecipeBundle\Entity\RecipeIngredient $ingredients)
{
    $this->ingredients->removeElement($ingredients);
}

/**
 * Get ingredients
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getIngredients()
{
    return $this->ingredients;
}

/**
 * Set title
 *
 * @param string $title
 * @return Recipe
 */
public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get title
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->title;
}
}
```

and recipeIngredient

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Recipe", inversedBy="ingredients")
 * */
protected $recipe;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ingredient", inversedBy="ingredients" , cascade={"persist"})
 * */
protected $ingredient;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @var string  $quantity
 *
 */
protected $quantity;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @var string $unit
 *
 */
protected $unit;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set quantity
 *
 * @param string $quantity
 * @return RecipeIngredient
 */
public function setQuantity($quantity)
{
    $this->quantity = $quantity;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get quantity
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getQuantity()
{
    return $this->quantity;
}

/**
 * Set unit
 *
 * @param string $unit
 * @return RecipeIngredient
 */
public function setUnit($unit)
{
    $this->unit = $unit;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get unit
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getUnit()
{
    return $this->unit;
}

/**
 * Set recipe
 *
 * @param \Recipe\RecipeBundle\Entity\Recipe $recipe
 * @return RecipeIngredient
 */
public function setRecipe(\Recipe\RecipeBundle\Entity\Recipe $recipe = null)
{
    $this->recipe = $recipe;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get recipe
 *
 * @return \Recipe\RecipeBundle\Entity\Recipe
 */
public function getRecipe()
{
    return $this->recipe;
}

/**
 * Set ingredient
 *
 * @param \Recipe\RecipeBundle\Entity\Ingredient $ingredient
 * @return RecipeIngredient
 */
public function setIngredient(\Recipe\RecipeBundle\Entity\Ingredient $ingredient = null)
{
    $this->ingredient = $ingredient;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get ingredient
 *
 * @return \Recipe\RecipeBundle\Entity\Ingredient
 */
public function getIngredient()
{
    return $this->ingredient;
}
}
```

Comment: Show us how you persist `RecipieIngredient`...

Comment: Yes, this code seems to be fine .... As Gremo says, please show us more details

Comment: Best guess from this is you're not explicitly setting the Recipe instance into the RecipeIngredient instance, and as RI is the owning side the relationship isn't persisted to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic idea is the correct one. If you want to have a ManyToMany relation, but you need to add extra fields in the join table, the way to go is exactly as you have described: using a new entity having 2 ManyToOne relations and some additional fields.

Unfortunately you have not provided your controller code, because most likely your problem is there.

Basically if you do something like:

```
$ri = new RecipeIngredient;
$ri->setIngredient($i);
$ri->setRecipe($r);
$ri->setQuantity(1);
$em->persist($ri);
$em->flush();
```

You should always get a correct record in your database table having both recipe_id and ingredient_id filled out correctly.

Checking out your code the following should also work, although I personally think this is more sensitive to mistakes:

```
$ri = new RecipeIngredient;
$ri->setIngredient($i);
$ri->setQuantity(1);
// here we assume that Recipe->addIngredient also does the setRecipe() for us and 
// that the cascade field is set correctly to cascade the persist on $ri
$r->addIngredient($ri);
$em->flush();
```

For further reading I would suggest the other topics on this subject, such as: [Doctrine2: Best way to handle many-to-many with extra columns in reference table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542243/doctrine2-best-way-to-handle-many-to-many-with-extra-columns-in-reference-table)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this model correctly the construction of a recipe and its associated recipeIngredients are concurrent. You might not have an id until you persist and without an id if receipeIngredient->setRecipe() is called the default null will be place in the recipeIngredient->recipe field.  This is often handled with cascade: "persist" (not present for the recipe field in your example, but you can handle it explicitly in the controller:

```
/** 
  * Creates a new Recipe entity.
  *
  */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $form = $this->createForm(new RecipeType());  
  $form->bind($request);

  if ($form->isValid()){
    $data = $form->getData();
    $recipeId = $data->getId();
    $recipeIngredients=$data->getIngredients();
    $recipe=$em->getRepository('reciperecipeBundle:Recipe')
               ->findOneById($RecipeId);
    if (null === $Recipe)
      {$Recipe=new Recipe();}  
    foreach ($recipeIngredients->toArray() as $k => $i){
      $recipeIngredient=$em->getRepository('reciperecipeBundle:recipeIngredient')
                           ->findOneById($i->getId());
      if (null === $recipeIngredient)
        {$recipeIngrediente=new RecipeIngredient();}  
      $recipe->addIngredient($i);

      // Next line *might* be handled by cascade: "persist"        
      $em->persist($recipeIngredient);
    }  
    $em->persist($Recipe);
    $em->flush();
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('Recipe', array()));
  }   

  return $this->render('reciperecipeBundle:Recipe:new.html.twig'
                      ,array('form'   => $form->createView()));  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not really sure if this would be a solution, but its easy yo try it, and probably it will help. 
When I create a relationshiop of this kind, I use to write another anotation, the  **@ORM\JoinColumn**, like in this example:

We have an entity A, an entity B, and an class AB wich represents the relationships, and adds some other fields, like in you case.

My relationship would be as follows:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 *  
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="a_rel_b")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class AB
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *  @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="A", inversedBy="b")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="a_id", referencedColumnName="id")  
     **/

    private $a;


    /**
     * @var integer
     *  @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="B", inversedBy="a")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="b_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $b;
// ...
```

**name** means the name of the field in the relationship table, while **referencedColumnName** is the name of the id field in the referenced entity table   (i.e b_id is a column in a_rel_b that references the column id in the table B )

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because it wouldn't be a relationship anymore [which is, by def, a subset of the cartesian product of the sets of the two original entities].

You need an intermediate entity, with references to both `Recipe` and `Ingredient` - call it `RecipeElement`, `RecipeEntry` or so, and add the fields you want.

Either, you can add a map to your `Recipe`, in which you save the attributes for each `Ingredient` you save, easy to maintain if there are no duplicates.

For further reading, [have a look at this popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542243/doctrine2-best-way-to-handle-many-to-many-with-extra-columns-in-reference-table).