# How to map connection between three tables

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have three tables:

- game `columns: id | name` (eg. 1 | Halo)
- own `columns: id | type_id | type_name` (eg. 1 | 1 | on wishlist)
- user `columns: id | name` (eg. 1 | Tomek)

Now what I have is a `ManyToMany` connection between those tables:

**User** (table `user_own`)

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Own")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="type_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
```

**Own** (table `own_game`)

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Game")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="game_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
```

My query:

```
public function getOwned() {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('
                SELECT u, o, g FROM AcmeGoBundle:User u
                JOIN u.owners o
                JOIN u.games g
            ')
            ->getResult();
    }
```

I can retrieve **games** owned by particular **user**, but I can't connect **type** of ownership. How can I do this?

Comment: You just need to tables - `User` and `Game`. Doctrine will take care of creating the join table.

Comment: I have `user` and `game` tables. I need to write `ManyToMany` between them?

Comment: Yes, if your app has such relationship [which I do believe].

Comment: I did so, and it didn't helped me at all. I placed my query in question, maybe it needs corrections.

Comment: [Go through the tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/doctrine.html) so you can get a better clue on how Doctrine works.

Comment: From your `getOwned` method [which lies were? in the entity?] it seems pretty clear you don't have a clue about how the ORM works, so I addressed you with a meaningful resource. If you find it pointless I am sorry - good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To crate `ManyToMany` with additional column with some data you need to create this by hand.

Doctrine `ManyToMany` relation crates a join table with id's of joined entities. So you need to create by your own Entity named ex. `UserOwns` with `OneToMany` relation to `User` and another `OneToMany` relation `Own`. Then you can add additional field with your data inside.

Check that question: [Doctrine2: Best way to handle many-to-many with extra columns in reference table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542243/doctrine2-best-way-to-handle-many-to-many-with-extra-columns-in-reference-table)