# How to add an entity in Symfony 2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have made a table in a database and that table is connected to symfony2 and when I have already develop the application I have find out that I have to add column to the table called profilePicture for uploading profile pics and I have already generated the entities from the previous version of the table and now my question is

How can I add an entity from the new version of the table ?

Comment: I'm guessing here but .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941358/add-a-column-to-an-existing-entity-in-symfony may help - your question could use some work.

Comment: Please add the program you have attempted.

Comment: @Nidhin David may i ask about your hangouts so that I can have a direct chat with you and I can let you see my code i ma quite a beginner in symfony

Answer (score 0):

The first thing which I advise you to make is to show the effort that you made (show at least some lines of codes).

You have to modify manually your entities and then make both following instructions in the console:

`# generate getter and setter
 php app/console doctrine:generate:entities YourBundle/Entity/YourClass`

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Finally, look at these two link, I think this is very helpful
[Official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/doctrine.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941358/add-a-column-to-an-existing-entity-in-symfony).

Comment: may I know your google hangouts name or email add so that I can have a direct chat with you and let you see my work because I'm new to the industry. I'm new to stackoverflow and symfony .. i cannot anymore ask questions in stackoverflow because I have been banned for six days because my questions are not that good

Comment: @vip_noob I deeply recommend you to read this ! https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140812110219-142144287-why-stack-overflow-is-part-of-my-daily-routine?trk=prof-post

Comment: i thank you for the recommendation now I have the courage to discover the inner skills that I have ...