# Doctrine2 with Symfony2: Why does cascade persist not work on this many-to-many relationship?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, cascade

In my project I got many `many-to-many` entities. This `many-to-many` relations have attributes, so i decided to split them up in `A 1:n B n:1 C` like it [is described in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542243/doctrine2-best-way-to-handle-many-to-many-with-extra-columns-in-reference-table).

So my reduced class structure looks like below. So far so good, but when I run my controller (also listed below) to insert values i got an exception:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO b (...) VALUES (...)' with params {...}
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'class_a_id' cannot be null

What am I doing wrong?

#### Class A

```
<?
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="a")
 */
class ClassA {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     **/
    protected $id;

    /** OTHER FIELDS **/

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ClassB", mappedBy="class_a", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     **/
    protected $class_b;
}
```

#### Class B

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="b")
 */
class ClassB {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     **/
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ClassC", inversedBy="class_b")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="class_c_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     **/
    protected $class_c;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ClassA", inversedBy="class_b")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="class_a_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     **/
     protected $class_a;

    /** OTHER FIELDS **/
}
```

#### Class C

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="c")
 */
class ClassC {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /** OTHER FIELDS **/

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ClassB", mappedBy="class_c")
     **/
    protected $class_b;
}
```

#### Controller

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$a = new ClassA();
$a->setXXX() //Setting some other fields
foreach(...) {
    $b = new ClassB();
    $b->setClass_C(...); //found by doctrine out of database and set into classB
    $b->setXXX() //Setting some other fields
    $a->addClass-B($b); //added ClassB into ClassA
}
$em->persist($a);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but it looks like the issue might be that the ClassA object isn't a managed object before you add the classB to it.  Just a shot in the dark but if you persist $a before the foreach loop, what happens?

Comment: @KenHannel thanks for your help! Solved my problem. You can see it in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for thinking about my problem, but solved it already!
The problem can be easily solved by adding just class a into b. so my controller works now. See the difference below:

#### Controller

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$a = new ClassA();
$a->setXXX() //Setting some other fields
foreach(...) {
    $b = new ClassB();
    $b->setClass_C(...); //found by doctrine out of database and set into classB
    $b->setXXX() //Setting some other fields
    $a->addClass-B($b); //added ClassB into ClassA
    $b->setClass_A($a); //add ClassA into Class B !!NEW!!
}
$em->persist($a);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: Yeah, that's an easy way to fix it. This is basically the exact behavior that I would have expected out of the cascade operation. If you're going to use this fix through all of your code then I would recommend removing the cascade from your ORM definitions.  We ran into an issue where we were getting unexpected behavior and we ended up tracking it down to a cascade definition that was never removed.

Comment: @KenHannel thanks for this hint. i will prove this im my project :)