# Symfony2 + doctrine2 table relation design

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I'm using Symfony2 with doctrine2 and I need to design table relation with yml file.
The tables are: users, account and roles where users can be members of many accounts and have there different role.

Without doctrine I would create tables and one joining table with user_id,account_id and role_id.

With doctrine I have now this and I'm looking for a hint how to add there one more relation to table roles.

```
User:
    type: entity
    manyToMany:
        accounts:
          targetEntity: Accounts
          joinTable:
            name: UserAccount
            joinColumns:
              user_id:
                referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
              account_id:
                referencedColumnName: id
```

Comment: So is the role also dependent of the account?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doctrine2: Best way to handle many-to-many with extra columns in reference table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542243/doctrine2-best-way-to-handle-many-to-many-with-extra-columns-in-reference-table)

Answer (score 0):

In such case the only way you can go is create another entity called, let say `UserAccountRole` and connect to it with `OneToMany`.

```
User -> (OneToMany) -> UserAccountRole -> (ManyToOne) -> User
Account -> (OneToMany) -> UserAccountRole -> (ManyToOne) -> Account
Role -> (OneToMany) -> UserAccountRole -> (ManyToOne) -> Role
```