# Doctrine2 - Many-to-many Association with association type

Tags: doctrine-orm

Is it possible to create an external field in Association in Doctrine2. The main purpose is to have a type of association.

For example,
We have Contacts and Opportunities. I need the association between Contacts and Opportunities with a type of this association.

Example of data:

```
contact_id   | opportunity_id   | association_type
------------------------------------------------------
<contact_id> | <opportunity_id> | <Executive Sponsor>    
<contact_id> | <opportunity_id> | <Business Evaluator>
```

Is it possible to implement in Doctrine2?

Here is my association (YAML):

```
Opportunity:
  type: entity
  table: opportinity
  ...
  ...
  ...
  manyToMany:
    contacts:
      targetEntity: Contact
      joinTable:
        name: opportinities_contacts
        joinColumns:
          opportunity_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
        inverseJoinColumns:
          contact_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doctrine2: Best way to handle many-to-many with extra columns in reference table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542243/doctrine2-best-way-to-handle-many-to-many-with-extra-columns-in-reference-table)

Answer (score 1):

The best practice in this case is to create an Entity Association Class.

Basically, split your Many-To-Many relationship into a pair of Many-to-one with a new class inbetween

Create a new class "ContactOpportunities" (In my organization we name them ToMap => ContactToOpportunityMap that sits between the classes.

```
class ContactOpportunity {

    /**
     * @var <FQN>\Contact
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="<FQN>\Contact", inversedBy='opportunities')
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name='Contact_ID', referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
    protected $contact;


    /**
     * @var <FQN>\Opportunity
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="<FQN>\Opportunity", inversedBy='contacts')
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name='Opportunity_ID', referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
    protected $opportunity;

    /*
     * @var string type
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Association_Type", type="string")
    protected $type;
 }
```

Or in yml...

```
ContactOpportunity
  type: entity
  table: opportunities_contacts
  ...
  ...
  ...
  manyToOne:
    targetEntity: Contact
    inversedBy: opportunities
    joinColumn:
      name: contact_id
      referencedColumnName: id
  manyToOne:
    targetEntity: Opportunity
    inversedBy: contacts
    joinColumn:
      name: opportunity_id
      referencedColumnName: id
```

Then convert your existing classes to target this new class:

```
Opportunity:
  type: entity
  table: opportunity
  ...
  ...
  ...
  oneToMany:
    contacts:
      targetEntity: ContactOpportunity
      mappedBy: opportunity

Contact:
  type: entity
  table: contact
  ...
  ...
  ...
  oneToMany:
    opportunities:
      targetEntity: ContactOpportunity
      mappedBy: contact
```