# How to tell doctrine:mapping:import to create own entity instead of junction-table

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have three tables:

- banners (id, url, img)
- banner_on_position (banner, position, loading)
- banner_positions (id, name)

When I run the doctrine:mapping:import, doctrine creates only two tables. Banners and BannerPositions. Auto-generation doesn't create an own entity for the banner_on_position table.

Is there a way to access the loading attribute with querybuilder?
OR
How to tell doctrine to create own entity?

Until now I had no problems with auto generation of entities and it was very comfortable. I hope I don't have to create to code manually.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create code manually in that case. If your many_to_many table have some extra properties then you need to use that trick: Both side need to use `oneToMany` relation for `banner_on_position` and `banner_on_position` need to have `manyToOne` to both tables.

Check how we did it in similar case (ContainerWidget have link to container, widget and custom parameter - position). https://github.com/superdesk/web-publisher/blob/master/src/SWP/Bundle/TemplateEngineBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/ContainerWidget.orm.yml

Here is also really good question and answers on stackoverflow: [Doctrine2: Best way to handle many-to-many with extra columns in reference table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542243/doctrine2-best-way-to-handle-many-to-many-with-extra-columns-in-reference-table)