# Symfony - Dynamically add options to extended choice field on Sonata Admin

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

On my Sonata Admin I have two 'choice' fields.

Options on these list are getted with AJAX.

1. The first list is classic - 'multiple' & 'extended' to false.
2. The second has to be 'multiple' & 'extended', and so, create checkboxes.

For the first list, I can add my options with some JS/Jquery ( append('option') ) but I looking for a solution to create the checkboxes of the second list.

Is there any twig helper ou something else to do this?

Thanks for help!

**EDIT:**

To be more precise, I want to do two dependents fields (and so, dynamically add options on these list)

Comment: can you please explain what you mean by "The second has to be 'multiple' & 'extended', and so, create checkboxes." ?

Comment: It's the field options. My field is defined as it: ->add('weeks', 'choice',array('required'=> false, 'multiple' => true, 'expanded'=>true, 'mapped' => false)). This configuration create a checkbox group instead of a select

Comment: This helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542243/doctrine2-best-way-to-handle-many-to-many-with-extra-columns-in-reference-table