# Filter children in Doctrine Entity as property and mutate/hydrate form input

Tags: doctrine, symfony, entity-relationship, symfony-forms

I'm developing an article database with API endpoints using Symfony 3.2 and Doctrine 2.5. In the request body, I have an Author:

```
{
   "article": {
       "title": "Some article",
       "author": {
           "email": "someone@something.com",
           "name": "Howard Wedothis"
       }
   }
}
```

I'd like to store an Update entity with a datetime, article ID and the Author ID. In order to do this currently, I'm having to post the following:

```
{
    "article": {
        "title": "Some article",
        "updates": [{
            "author": {
                "email": "someone@something.com",
                "name": "Howard Wedothis"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

This isn't as elegant IMO.

**First question:** What's the best way to mutate/hydrate the simple author fields and store an Update against the article and author? Authors and Articles are ManyToMany but I'd like to avoid posting an array of one for readability reasons mostly.

**Second question:** Is it possible to add properties to the article entity for `created` and `lastUpdated` to display the first and last update respectively from the article without injecting a repository into the entity?

i.e.

```
$article->getCreated() // returns first Update
$article->getLastUpdated() // returns last Update
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved this by adding the Author and overriding the Author on updates and using the Lifecycle Events to create a new Update entity on PrePersist and PreUpdated as suggested by @Matko.

Request Data:

```
{
   "article": {
       "title": "Some article",
       "author": {
           "email": "someone@something.com",
           "name": "Howard Wedothis"
       }
   }
}
```

Article.php:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="articles")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @return Update
     */
    public function getCreated(): Update
    {
        return $this->updates->first();
    }

    /**
     * @return Update
     */
    public function getLastUpdated(): Update
    {
        return $this->updates->last();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function addUpdate(): void
    {
        $update = new Update();
        $update->setAuthor($this->getAuthor());
        $update->setArticle($this);
        $this->updates->add($update);
    }
}
```

This method does sort of invalidate the Author of the entity but keeps the article history.

Comment: I think you have to handle many-to-many relationship with extra columns in reference table:

You can take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542243/doctrine2-best-way-to-handle-many-to-many-with-extra-columns-in-reference-table

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the second question - use **Lifecycle Callbacks**

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/** 
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Author
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $updatedAt;

    /**
     * Get id.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdAt.
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     *
     * @return this
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt.
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set modifiedAt.
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedAt.
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function updatedTimestamps()
    {
        $this->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));

        if ($this->getCreatedAt() == null) {
            $this->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
        }
    }
}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/lifecycle_callbacks.html
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events

Regarding your request examples, insert request and update request should have the same format. You are complicating your life with that **updates** key.

Use POST method for inserting article and PUT (you send complete article object) or PATCH (you send only fields that you want to update).

https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/rest/put-versus-post

https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony-rest/patch-programmer

Comment: Thanks - however by updating single fields, I'll lose the Author information. If one person creates the article, another updates it, I don't have the update information. Hence wanting to keep a revision/update history.

Comment: Regarding the POST/PUT etc. yes - this is how the API is working - the examples were highlighting the issue with the key rather than the method. So I'm looking to create this more detailed meta information from the author key alone, without having to specify that full payload in the request