# How to create other columns inside the intermediary table of a many-to-many relationship in Symfony?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

There are two entities having a many-to-many relationship :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=KbFavorisRepository::class)
 */
class KbFavoris
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    ...

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|KbCollection[]
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="KbCollection", mappedBy="kb_favoris",cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $collection;

    ...

}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=KbCollectionRepository::class)
 */
class KbCollection
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @JMS\Groups({"list_collection"})
     */
    private $id;

    ...

    /**
     * @var KbFavoris
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="KbFavoris",inversedBy="collection", cascade={"remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *  name="kb_favoris_collection",
     *  joinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="collection_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  },
     *  inverseJoinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="favoris_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  }
     * )
     */
    private $kb_favoris;

    ...

}
```

How to add another column inside the intermediary table of the many-to-many relationship ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Doctrine2: Best way to handle many-to-many with extra columns in reference table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542243/doctrine2-best-way-to-handle-many-to-many-with-extra-columns-in-reference-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add some extra fields, you need to create another entity;
Ex:

```
class KbFavoris
{
    // OneToMany here to KbFavorisKbCollection, is array|collection
}

class KbCollection 
{
    // OneToMany here to KbFavorisKbCollection , is array|collection
}
```

And the new class :

```
class KbFavorisKbCollection 
{
   // ManyToOne here to KbFavoris (represent one KbFavoris)
   // ManyToOne here to KbCollection (represent one KbCollection )
}
```